# Do all browsers ignore nameless input fields?

Tags: html, http-post, forms, input-field, name-attribute

Is it guaranteed that a browser doesn't send an input element if it doesn't have the name attribute specified?

For example, can we assume that POSTing the form below won't send the credit card number?

```
<form action="/process" method="post">
  <input id="credit-card-number" type="text">
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Comment: Impossible to say whether "all browsers" handle the spec correctly. But all browsers that matter do.

Comment: What makes you ask this? Prompting for a credit card number *looks* risky, so why would you do that if you don’t want to send it?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela By not sending credit card information to your server the PCI-compliance criteria is significantly dropped. In this case, we validate other order information over AJAX. Once validated, we generate a hidden credit card form on the fly which we send to the gateway provider, thus dodging the huge responsibility.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it guaranteed that a browser doesn't send an input element if it doesn't have the name attribute specified?

Yes (unless you muck about with JavaScript to change that).

The specification is quite clear that [controls without names cannot be successful](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2).

> A successful control must be defined within a FORM element and must have a control name.

Answer (score 0):

The standard says that to send an input it should be a successful "control."

If a control doesn't have a `name` it's not a successful "control," so it should *not*  be sent.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html